# Add headers in csv file using azure data factory while moving to sink

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

How can we add headers to the files existing in the blob/ azure data lake using azure data factory.
I am using a copy activity to move the header less files to the sink, but while moving the files should have default headers like "Prop_0" or "Column_1". Any method available to achieve the same?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks and Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

In usually, Data factory will using the default header `Prop_0, Prop_1...Prop_N`  for the less header csv file  to help us copy the data, if we don't set the `first row as header`.

This is to help us do the column mapping but won't change the csv file.

According my experience and know about Data Factory, it doesn't support us do the schema change of the csv file. It's impossible to add the header of the csv files at least for now.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You Leon for the suggestion. I have created a power shell script to add dynamic headers to the files and now looking to call that script to pipeline and execute the same.

Comment: @SandeepThachan You're welcome. Now your question is turn to how to call that script to pipeline and execute the same. It's hard to answer you, I haven't met this problem. You could post it as a new question, maybe others can give you more suggestions. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, create a new Data Flow. Add your CSV source with a no header dataset. Then add your Sink with a dataset that writes to ADLS G2 folder as a text delimited file WITH headers. In the Sink Mapping, you can name your columns:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different solution. Used the 'no delimiter' option to keep all of them as one column. Then, In the derived column action, I split the single column into multiple columns and provided a proper name for each column. Now we can map the columns into the target table.